# How to check whether date and file uploading fields are not empty while submitting the html form

Tags: javascript

```html
<!-- it is working fine ,storing image in folder,name in database,and retrieve and view it in browser.--> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body bgcolor="pink">
<center>
<h3> FILE UPLOADING </h3>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
       
<form name=form1 action="new2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    
 Select image to upload:<input type="file" style="border: solid 1px black" name="file" id="file" size="80">
 <br> 
 <br>
 
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
</center>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
 if (!isset($_SESSION)) 
{
    session_start();
}
 
  $id= $_SESSION['id'];

$name=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
$extension=strtolower(substr($name,strpos($name,'.')+1));
$size=$_FILES["file"]["size"];
$type=$_FILES["file"]["type"];
$max_size=1000000;
$tmp_name=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
if(isset($name) && !empty($name))
{
if (($extension=='jpg'||$extension=='jpeg')&& ($type=='image/jpeg'||$type=='image/jpg') && $size<=$max_size)
{
$location='upload/';
if (file_exists($location.$name))
{
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.<br/>";
}
else
{
if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$location.$name))
{
echo $name.'UPLOADED!<br/>';
//echo 'NAME=',$name,'   TYPE=',$type,'      SIZE=',$size;
$result=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("couldnt connect");
mysql_select_db("sample") or die("couldnot select database");
mysql_query("insert into imagestore2 values ($id,'$name')");
if($result)
{
 echo "Image name saved into database<br/>";
}
else
{
 echo "Sorry,Couln't upload ur file<br/>";
}
}
else
{
echo 'There was an error<br/>';
}
}
}
else
{
echo'FILE MUST BE JPG/JPEG AND SIZE MUST BE 1MB OR LESS THAN THAT.<br/>';
}
}
else 
{ 
echo 'Please choose a file <br/>';
}
}

?>
<?php
//Retrieves data from MySQL
if (!isset($_SESSION)) 
{
    session_start();
}
 //if(isset($_POST['id']))
 //{
 $id= $_SESSION['id'];

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("Could not connect to the database");
mysql_select_db("sample") or die("Could not select database");
$data = mysql_query("SELECT `name` FROM imagestore2 where id='$id'") or
die(mysql_error());
//Puts it into an array
$file_path = 'http://localhost/projectwork/loginpage/upload/';
echo "UPLOADED IMAGES <br/>";
$count=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data))
{//Outputs the image and other data
$src=$file_path.$row['name'];
$count++;
echo "<img height=100 width=100 src=".$src."> &nbsp; &nbsp;";
}

?>
</center>
</body>
<!--reference http://jagdeepmalhi.blogspot.in/2011/02/phpmysql-store-file-path-in-database.html-->
</html>
```

I am having a HTML form with 2 fields (date of picture taken, image to upload). I want to upload the image through the submit button if the user has entered both fields. I already validated if the file uploading field is empty or not, and uploaded files using submit button. Now I am adding date field in the form tag and need to check that both are not empty. Can any one suggest how to do it with javascript?

Comment: How it is done right now? Show us some code..

Comment: Just check if both the `value` attributes aren't an empty string

Comment: [HTML <input> required Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp)?

Comment: here i added the code what i used to do the above mentioned task.Sofar i am having one field to select the image file to upload.Now i would like to add date field.Here i couldnt understand how to do this validation because ,i have already used php to chk whether 1.have i selected a image file or not..2.if not it wil warn me.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 var valueDate = document.getElementById('Date').value;
    if (!valueDate) {
        alert('Invalid date');
    }
```

Comment: i just checked the value attributes of both fields to empty  in javascript and it is working fine now.